# How to get create an APK file in a MAUI project to can distribute the Android application?

Tags: maui

I have a MAUI application and I would like to create the APK file to can distribute it, I don't want to publish it in the store.

I have try this:

- I set the project to release.
- I right click in the MAUI project and choose publish option.
- I click distribute button
- I select Ad Hoc
- I create a new signing identity

The only option to save is a .aac file, but I would like to have the .apk file.

How could I compile an .apk file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1.double click the `Properties` folder of your app, then you will open a page.

2.select `Android` option on the left -> `Options`-> set `Android package format` to `apk`.

Comment: Is this still valid? Our publish creates an x.aab file, when checking the settings these were already on apk